# Two ajax calls, both redirecting: can one request fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two sequential ajax post requests, both of which, on complete, will navigate the page.

Naturally I should check both returned before navigating, but I am curious: could the setup, as shown below, realistically make one of the requests fail?

By fail I mean the server will not receive/process it.

```js
function redirect(){
  window.location.href="./success";
}

//First call
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  complete:redirect
});
  
//Second call
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  complete:redirect
});
```

My thoughts: T1, first ajax call is made, T2, second ajax call is made, T3, first to return returns and redirect is made.

Since T3>T2, wouldn't the second call be made before the redirect? It doesn't have to return to be successful.

Comment: it depends. Chances are both will be sent successfully, then one will complete and redirect thus aborting the other. but the server very well could continue processing it, depending on timing. so, Yes, one request can fail. and, it can succeed.

Comment: regarding your edit, it again depends. This time it depends on the size of the request and the network. If the T2 request completely reaches the server bfeore the T1 request is responded to by the server, the server will likely process T2 even though the xhr client-side is aborted due to the redirect. but there's also the possibility that T2 finishes before T1 for the very same reason.

Comment: T3>>>T2, unless there is no connection, in which case both requests will fail anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both requests will be made. Whichever one finishes first will cause the browser to **cancel** the second one. But as Kevin B pointed out, your server will most likely continue processing it and will be unaware that the client cancelled it (at least this is the way it works with apache) until the server tries to send something back to the client (and even then it's a crapshoot depending on your architecture).

It's very important to note the distinction between a **failed** request and a **client cancelled** request. In your case, the browser will cancel any ajax request that is ongoing when the page is unloading, but that doesn't mean the server won't process the instructions it received from the request.

Answer (score 0):

yes, ajax calls are async, so to answer your question

from your two ajax request, if its on dom ready call, whichever will get complete response first will redirect your page and send ajax will eventually fail..

it would make both call at a time, but once your page is redirected your success callback will failed, in such cases if server engages the second page activity it will eventually fail. Also, how to what server will send success callback, it might happens that server will function successfully if redirect is just a client side.

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression the second call would always be made before the first one returned, since the call would take a while to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes one of the requests will probably fail as both requests are asynchronous and as soon as one of the requests get completed the page will be redirected thus cancelling the other request.

What you can do is define a variable and check for its value before redirecting.

```
    function redirect(){
      window.location.href="./success";
    }
   window.completed = 0; // if values is 2  that means both             requests are complete

//First call
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  complete:function(){
     window.complete++!
     if(window.complete == 2)
     {
          redirect();
     }
  }
});

//Second call
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  complete:function(){
     window.complete++!
     if(window.complete == 2)
     {
          redirect();
     }
  }
});
```